# How to evaluate inverser fourier transform?

Tags: ifft

A function $f(\tilde{\phi}_i,\tilde{\theta}_j)$ defined on the sphere. The interpolation or filtering of the function is depending on $K$. I am confused on how to perform inverse-transformation using $\mathrm{fftw}$.

$$
\begin{align}
f\left(\tilde{\phi}_i,\tilde{\theta}_j\right) &= \sum_{m=-K}^{K} \tilde{f}^{m}\left(\tilde{\theta}_j\right) e^{jm\tilde{\phi}_i} \\
\end{align}
$$

where, $\tilde{i}=0,...,\mathrm{I}-1$ amd $\tilde{j}=0,...,\mathrm{J}-1$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{I} =&\,\, 2\mathrm{L}+1 \\
\mathrm{J} =&\,\,\,\,\,  \mathrm{L}+1
\end{align}
$$

Further $\tilde{\phi}_i = \frac{2\pi\tilde{i}}{I}$ and plug it in the above equation

$$
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{2\pi\tilde{i}}{I},\tilde{\theta}_j\right) &= \sum_{m=-K}^{K} \tilde{f}^{m}\left(\tilde{\theta}_j\right) e^{jm\frac{2\pi\tilde{i}}{I}} \\
\end{align}
$$

then for $\tilde{j}=0,...,\mathrm{J}-1$ I need to evaluate the inverse.

If length of $m=2\mathrm{L}+1$ then I have no problem in setting up the vectors to perform inverse fourier-transformation. But if length of $m$ is other than $2\mathrm{L}+1$, then I have no understanding in the setup.